# This localhost page can't be found on rails start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

On `rails s`, the server is starting successfully without errors but on accessing `localhost:3000` it says,

```
"This localhost page can't be found",HTTP error 404
```

In the console, I can see that the page is loading successfully. Problem is that it is not getting displayed.

Does anyone know what may be the issue?
Previously the ruby code was working fine, suddenly I came across this issue.

Comment: Do you have any routes for landing page in application, please check routes.rb

Comment: How does your `routes.rb` look like? What exactly is written to the logs?

Comment: Check your root path in `routes.rb`

Comment: Are you running this local, or on a cloud server like Cloud9?

Comment: When you run "rails s" what port does it shows the server is running at?

Comment: @chaitanya My routes.rb has root route as root to: 'controllername#actionname'

Comment: @spickermann  Logs as "message :Processing by Controller#action  as HTML" (sorry am not supposed to reveal controller and action name). .Application specific id's and keys are being loaded properly which I can see in console. After loading , i can see a message in console  saying "Filter chain halted as :check version rendered or redirected"

Comment: @max pleaner  I am running it in Virtual box (mac Sierra)

Comment: @MarceloFonseca : Running on port 3000

Comment: @VishwasNahar : routes.rb is having only one root route

Comment: @PoojithaNv: Please share your `check version` before action.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually running on port 3000.  You could be on 5000 if you're running your app with a Procfile (foreman).

```
daniel@daniel-HP-ProBook-450-G1 ~/$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Double check that in your Rails log, you are actually running on Port 3000.  The line says `Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:<port number>`.